# How to pass cookie options in cookie-session 1.0.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I'm trying to learn the "cookie-session" module for Node. 
https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session

I have a hard time understanding how to pass options for the cookie. For example expiration. Default seems to be a year!

**This is the instructions about options for the cookie:** 
"Other options are passed to `cookies.get()` and `cookies.set()` allowing you to control security, domain, path, and signing among other settings."

But i dont get it! 
Am I supposed to require cookies module as well?
Or do I somehow change the options trough `var session = require('cookie-session')`?
I have tried `session.cookies.set()`, but that doesnt seems to work.

I have tried to read the sourcecode in the "cookie-session" and "cookies" module for clues, but I dont know what to look for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

Define the options you want to specify in the creation of the session, as illustrated in the docs: https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session.  They will be used when creating the cookie (including the `expires` option).

```
app.use(session({
  keys: ['key1', 'key2'],
  secureProxy: true // if you do SSL outside of node
  // more options here...
}))
```

### Long answer

Using the example above, when you pass in the configuration object into `session`, [you are sending this object into the function here](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session/blob/08c748853b883c87b34aed9d50ce4aff49a173d7/index.js#L18).  This `opts` is passed around, but in particular, [stored as `req.sessionOptions` here](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session/blob/08c748853b883c87b34aed9d50ce4aff49a173d7/index.js#L42).  `req` is passed in when creating a `new Session`, [and stored as `this._ctx`](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session/blob/08c748853b883c87b34aed9d50ce4aff49a173d7/index.js#L109-L110).  Finally, when `save` is called on the `Session`, [these options are pulled from the `sessionOptions` and used in the `set` call for the cookies](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session/blob/08c748853b883c87b34aed9d50ce4aff49a173d7/index.js#L184-L188):

```
Session.prototype.save = function(){
  var ctx = this._ctx;
  var json = this._json || encode(this);
  var opts = ctx.sessionOptions;
  var name = ctx.sessionKey;

  debug('save %s', json);
  ctx.sessionCookies.set(name, json, opts);
};
```

So the options you pass in originally are passed to the `set` call when creating the cookie.

Comment: Of course, I have misinterpret this completely. This line: 
"Other options are passed to cookies.get() and cookies.set()... "  tricked me into thinking that all other options has to be applied in another mystic way... but they are just passed on as you clarify =)