# How to use cookie-session for node expresss.js

Tags: node.js, express, express-session, cookie-session

As [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) is not ready to work on production environments unless you change the module to something like `redisStorage`, I decided to go for [cookie-session](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session).

The [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session#cookie-options) doesn't seem to be very clear to me.
It says

> Other options are passed to cookies.get() and cookies.set()

- What is `cookies` there?
- Does it mean we have to use `set` to set the options we want?

I was trying to use cookieSession as [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookie-options), but it seems that's not the way it works:

```
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');

app.use(cookieSession({
  maxAge: 20*60*1000, //20 mins
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
  secureProxy: true,
  keys: ['key1', 'key2']
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

I was in fact doing it in the right way. But because the documentation can be confusing I was not certain.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24066020/1081396) helped me to understand what documentation really means.